# unsafe memory internal error. android studio did'nt work or started

Tags: android, android-studio-2.1

Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.InternalError: a fault occurred in a recent unsafe memory access operation in compiled Java code
at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.copyMemoryChecks(Unsafe.java:831)
at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.copyMemory(Unsafe.java:800)
at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.ScopedMemoryAccess.copyMemoryInternal(ScopedMemoryAccess.java:167)
at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.ScopedMemoryAccess.copyMemory(ScopedMemoryAccess.java:149)
at java.base/java.nio.ByteBuffer.getArray(ByteBuffer.java:932)
at java.base/java.nio.ByteBuffer.get(ByteBuffer.java:800)
at com.intellij.util.lang.HashMapZipFile.readCentralDirectory(HashMapZipFile.java:207)
at com.intellij.util.lang.HashMapZipFile.createHashMapZipFile(HashMapZipFile.java:59)
at com.intellij.util.lang.ImmutableZipFile.populateFromCentralDirectory(ImmutableZipFile.java:276)
at com.intellij.util.lang.ImmutableZipFile.load(ImmutableZipFile.java:81)
at com.intellij.util.lang.ImmutableZipFile.load(ImmutableZipFile.java:54)
at com.intellij.util.lang.ZipResourceFile.(ZipResourceFile.java:33)
at com.intellij.util.lang.PathClassLoader.lambda$static$0(PathClassLoader.java:21)
at com.intellij.util.lang.ClassPath.createLoader(ClassPath.java:412)
at com.intellij.util.lang.ClassPath.getLoaderSlowPath(ClassPath.java:363)
at com.intellij.util.lang.ClassPath.findClassWithoutCache(ClassPath.java:223)
at com.intellij.util.lang.ClassPath.findClass(ClassPath.java:202)
at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:203)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.PathManager.platformPath(PathManager.java:755)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.PathManager.getDefaultConfigPathFor(PathManager.java:325)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.PathManager.getCustomOptionsDirectory(PathManager.java:359)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.PathManager.getCustomPropertiesFile(PathManager.java:592)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.PathManager.loadProperties(PathManager.java:547)
at com.intellij.idea.Main.bootstrap(Main.java:92)
at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:82)

---

Your JRE: 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-9586694 amd64 (JetBrains s.r.o.)
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr

can somebody fix it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.